# BigQuery failing to import CSV from tshark

Tags: csv, awk, google-bigquery

Currently, I have tshark logging all packets matching a certain messaging criteria and outputting them into a CSV. The CSVs are then stored on Google CloudStorage ready for importing into BigQuery.

This is one example line from the CSV that tshark outputs.

```
"1380106851.793056000",
"1.1.1.1",
"2.2.2.2",
"99999",
"1111",
"raw:ip",
"324",
"af:00:21:9a",
"880",
"102",
"74:00",
"ORIG",
"It's text or !\x0a\" 's not D",
"0x00",
"0",
```

BigQuery will not import this line claiming that "Data between close double quote (") and field separator: field starts with: ". I assume it is the 13th column ("It's text or !\x0a\" 's not D") that is causing this issue, but I'm unsure of how to negate it. This column contains the message text and it is reasonable to assume that it may never contain balanced syntax.

The only remedy that I can think of is running awk over the file and replacing any non-syntax double-quotes with single quotes.

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: Can you alter the `configuration.load.fieldDelimiter` and `configuration.load.quote` properties of your BigQuery configuration?  If so, I'd try using a char like `\001` ( or some other char that "can never show up" ) to delimit on CSV creation and data load.  As well, the double quoting of the data would need to be turned off on both ends.

Comment: So far I've only experimented with the job creator in the GUI - but I shall do a custom job to test. The message data is generated by users, so it will almost certainly contain a lot of random characters. I just need to avoid it escaping the quote.

Comment: Trying to reproduce this: I see multiple lines in the example, instead of multiple columns. What's the raw format?

Comment: Sorry, I added line breaks so that it is easy on the eye. The delimiter is a comma and all of the text in the original post is a single line (remove line breaks). I've managed to get sed to replace all of the double quotes, inside double quotes with single quotes using this; sed -e "s/\"\"/'/g" inputfile.csv -i    BigQuery seems to be okay with that. This, I can easily incorporate into a shell script before the file gets uploaded. Just a shame that BigQuery doesn't seem to handle the columns like MySQL.

Comment: found problem: quotes shouldn't be quoted like this \", but like this "" - full answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why tshark escapes double quotes with a backslash, but according to [RFC 4180](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization), they should be quoted with a double quote:

> "A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two
>   (double) quote characters."

BigQuery will happily ingest a quote escaped in this way:

- Doesn't work: "It's text or !\x0a\" 's not D"
- Works: "It's text or !\x0a"" 's not D"

Is there a way to tell tshark how to appropriately escape CSV? Otherwise I bet it would be a welcomed patch, if citing RFC standards. Also, if necessary this alternate escape mechanism could be implemented as a BigQuery feature (I guess votes in this question can act as measure of how much it's needed).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this makes total sense but I'm not sure if it is tshark that's escaping the quotes. The content may have been what was in the original packet. I will check for a reoccurance of this and cross reference it with the original PCAP. If it is the original packet content, I think I may have to iterate over it with sed to adjust the content before it is imported.

Comment: Looking at the original PCAPs, the double quote (") is definitely present but it is not escaped as per RFC 4180. In fact, it is not escaped at all. The slashes are part of the original text in the packet too. As BigQuery adheres to the RFC, it might have to be a patch for tshark? Not many CSV parsers can handle malformed formats,  so it's incredibly difficult to fix once it has been written.

Comment: Yes, tshark needs to handle escaping somehow so we can get valid CSV. It's weird this isn't already handled. Did you try http://ask.wireshark.org/?

Comment: I shall post an article there. In the meantime, I've found that PHP's str_getcsv will read CSVs that are non-compliant. From there, you can manipulate it and rewrite it using fputcsv, which prepares a CSV that BigQuery has no issues with at all. Also, I've noticed that you cannot call any of the CloudSDK utilities from scripts run from Cron - a symlink into /bin for the utilities required gets around this. Thanks for your help :)